# Where is `EitherT`'s Applicative instance defined?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, applicative

I don't see it [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-either-0.1.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Either.html#t:EitherT) by the definition of `EitherT`, nor [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html) by the definition of `Applicative`.

Shouldn't it be defined within the type module or within the typeclass module, to avoid being orphaned? Where is it?

Answer (score 4):

The [docs page you linked](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-either-0.1.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Either.html#t:EitherT) for `EitherT` clearly shows that `EitherT` is a type alias:

> `type EitherT =` [`ExceptT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html#t:ExceptT)
>
> Type alias for [ExceptT](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-either-0.1.2/docs/ExceptT.html)

That means it cannot have its own instances; any instances it has will be defined for the type it is an alias *for*; in this case `ExceptT`.

Conveniently, it also links to the docs for `ExceptT`. Inconveniently, it links those two occurrences of `ExceptT` to different URLs! One of them seems to be a broken link (to a module that exists in `mtl`, as if it existed in the `transformers-either` package), but the other one works, and shows:

```
(Functor m, Monad m) => Applicative (ExceptT e m)
```

Answer (score 3):

`EitherT` is defined as `type EitherT = ExceptT`. Unlike `newtype` wrappers which need their own instances, `type` synonyms share instances. And the instance for `ExceptT` is defined in [`Control.Monad.Trans.Except` in the `transformers` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#t:ExceptT).